# Pagination on queryset on only a segment of the page and not the whole page

Tags: django, pagination

I have a page with projects for a specific category that begins with the top-x most earned projects, followed by the top-x most viewed and the third segment contains all (other) projects for this category.

This third segment is long as it contains all projects for this specific category. Therefore, I would like to paginate them. But with standard pagination going to the next page will refresh the page, ending on the top of the page, needing to scroll down again to the third section (every single time you select the next page), which isn't very user friendly.

I saw a site (kickstarter) where they were able to paginate only one segment of the page, leaving the other parts of the site untouched, which is exactly what I want. But I am a novice and I have no idea how to do this.

Thanks for any ideas and help!

**My HTML code:**

```
{% for project in projects|dictsortreversed:"created_date"%}
            {% if project.num_days > 0 %}
                <div class="row no-gutters">
                        <div class="offset-1 col-4 mb-5 ">
                            {% if project.image %}
                            <a href="{% url 'project_detail' project.id %}" target="_blank">
                                <img class="img-fluid mt-5" src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{ project.image }}">
                            </a>
                            {% else %}
                            <a href="{% url 'project_detail' project.id %}" target="_blank">
                                <img class="img-fluid mt-5" src="{% static 'img/No-image-available.png' %}" alt="no image available">
                            </a>
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                        <div class="offset-1 col-6 mt-5">
                            <a href="{% url 'project_detail' project.id %}" target="_blank">
                                <h3 class="maintext">{{ project.title}}</h3>
                            </a>
                            <p class="subtext">{{ project.category }}</p>
                            <p>{{ project.description |truncatewords:60}}</p>
                            <p class="subtext mb-5">goal: ${{project.goal}} &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp  ends in: {{ project.num_days }} days</p>
                        </div>
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor%}
```

**My view code**

```
def get_project_category(request, project_category):
    """
    Projects for a specific category

    """
    projects = Project.objects.filter(
        category=Category.objects.get(category=project_category).id).order_by('-created_date')
    projects.category = project_category
    
    calculations(projects)
        
    context = {
        'projects': projects,

    }

    return render(request, 'project_category.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used https://datatables.net/manual/installation.

It makes a table with automatic search options and pagination. It paginates without having to start on top of the page.

AFter that I used CSS to eliminate the styling as a table. So made the header invisible and added an additional column in the table to create spacing between my images and text.